# User can't see tests on cards

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

A user in my organization can't see the icon for tests on board cards.
I have checked permissions and compared to another user who CAN see the icon and as far as I can find they have the same permissions.

[image: example of card WITH test icon]

If the user opens the card the tests are shown under "Related Work" -> "Tested By".

[image: example of opened card with test visible]

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ask the user who can't see the test icon to check with the following steps:

1. Clean the cache of the web browsers, then try opening the board page again.
2. Try opening the board page with different web browsers.
3. Try opening the board page with the private/incognito window of the web browsers.
4. On the machines of the users who can see the test icon, login to DevOps with the account of the user who can't see the icon, then open the board page.

**[UPDATE]**

What is the access level of this user?

In private projects, **Stakeholder** users only have partial access on Azure Boards, and can't manage test cases. Even if the **Stakeholder** users gain the project admin permission.

So, the user who is **Stakeholder** level can't see the test icon on the User Story card.

To view more details, you can see "[**About access levels**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops)".

Comment: The user has now tried all those steps but it still doesn't show the icon.

Comment: Hi @Joakim de Jong, I have update my answer. Please check it.

Comment: I had missed the access level. Changed it to Basic and now the user can see the test icon.  Thank you!